# Перебор каждого элемента столбца матрицы

Tags: c++

Мне нужно отсортировать элементы в каждом столбце матрицы. Как можно составить цикл для перебора каждого элемента в столбце(без сортировки)? Пробовал вот так, но это не то

`for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("%4d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }`

Comment: Т.е. нужно написать обычный цикл обработки матрицы, только не по строкам а по столбцам?

Comment: Не уверен, что Вы имеете ввиду. Мне нужно будет сравнивать элементы каждого столбца

Comment: Т.е. сортировка столбцов матрицы?

Comment: их элементов {1,3,2} -> {1,2,3}

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < count_columns; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < count_rows; j++) {
        printf("%4d", arr[j][i]);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

count_columns - количество столбцов

count_rows - количество строк

внимание нужно обратить на **arr[j][i]**